# navigation.navigate() doesn't work on my nested navigations

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here I'am testing with react navigation v6.

When I press "Go To Log-In" button,

it prints "navigation.navigate is not a function.

Here is my Main Navigation

```
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="User" component={MainStackNavigator} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notification" component={BottomTabNavigator} 
      options={ { headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} /> }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

here is my one of my nested Navigation

```
const MainStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Item" component={Items} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="LogIn" component={LogIn} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={Detail} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const ContactStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Here is my Log in Button in a component named "Items"

```
export default function Items(navigation) {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ITem navi: ", navigation);
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Items !</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Log-In" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('LogIn')} />
      <AccountList />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I'am stuck in this error for hours.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing it the wrong way

this line

```
export default function Items(navigation) {
```

Should be

```
export default function Items({navigation}) {
```

Basically you will get all the props as a single parameter which you can destruct and access the navigation prop

Answer (score 0):

In your code complier don't know what is **navigation** so you need wrap that in porps params like below

```
export default function Items({navigation}) {
```